# Is it normal to hear a noise when shaking a Nikon AF-S Nikkor 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6G VR?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, image-stabilization, sound

Whenever I shake the back side of the lens near my ear, I hear a sound, like something is moving inside the lens. However, it is working properly when mounted. Is this normal?

Comment: How hard are you shaking the lens, and how loud is the sound? Can you better describe what it sounds like?

Comment: I am shaking it slowly and sound is also low . I seems that some type of hollow ring is striking  .

Comment: However it is working properly when mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear the faintest jiggle when I shake my lens (and I'm not shaking it very hard).  I think my sound comes from the zoom ring moving slightly.  I can feel some internal movement but I don't hear anything.

For what it's worth, I bought my lens on eBay, and it's suffered some shocks since I've owned it.  Nothing major. I think it's in good shape.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal to hear some clicking sound by shaking a lens, because of AF mechanism. Zoom lenses and VR make more noise because they are made of moving parts.